# Sample by groupy with a condition (r)

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I need to randomly select a diary for each individual (id) but only for those who filled more than one.

Let us suppose my data look like this

```
dta = rbind(c(1, 1, 'a'), 
      c(1, 2, 'a'), 
      c(1, 3, 'b'), 
      c(2, 1, 'a'), 
      c(3, 1, 'b'), 
      c(3, 2, 'a'), 
      c(3, 3, 'c'))

colnames(dta) <- c('id', 'DiaryNumber', 'type')
dta = as.data.frame(dta)
dta

  id     DiaryNumber type
  1             1    a
  1             2    a
  1             3    b
  2             1    a
  3             1    b
  3             2    a
  3             3    c
```

For example, id 1 filled 3 diaries. What I need is to randomly select one of the 3 diaries. Id 2 only filled one diary, so I do not need to do anything with it.

I have no idea how I could do that. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sample_n`:

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(1)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## Groups: id
## 
##   id DiaryNumber type
## 1  1           2    a
## 2  2           1    a
## 3  3           1    b
```

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- lapply(split(dta, dta$id), function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ])
do.call("rbind", df)
```

Output:

```
  id DiaryNumber type
1  1           1    a
2  2           1    a
3  3           2    a
```